# how to get rect from a stateless widget in flutter

Tags: widget, flutter, rect, stateless

we can get the rect from from a stateful widget by adding global key to it, but
how to get the rect from a stateless widget in flutter? as all the fields in a stateless widget must be final, I can't add global key to it.

Comment: You can keep the global key reference somewhere else. No need to keep it in the widget itself.

Comment: You shouldn't. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @rémi-rousselet
I need to get the rect for this stateless widget so that I can show a menu at this widget's position.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer
Thanks, below code works well:
    GlobalKey _myKey = new GlobalKey();
    Text _myText = Text('123',key: _myKey);